# Sequential run of tests in SBT: Are these configurations the same?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Are these 2 settings alternatives or are both necessary to run the tests sequentially ?

```
Global / concurrentRestrictions += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
```

And :

```
parallelExecution := false
```

Another question :

Does the first configuration guarantee to have only one task per all the tests whatever it is their Test Suite?